# How might I reset state of just one reducer when I have multiple reducers and prevent reload on state reset of just one reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reducers

I maintain the data entered by a user in form in a reducer's state.I also have another reducer that has state related to some other functionality.Now I have  a reset button for form,clicking which,I want the state update for only the formReducer and not for the other reducer's state.Also I don't want my app to reload on formReducer's state reset

Have added the code snippet that I used to implement the functionality,but what happens is that the whole app reloads on clicking reset and states for both reducers eventually get reset
My index.js has the following code

```
   const appReducers = combineReducers({
       r1: reducer1, 
       formSubmissionReducer: formSubmissionReducer
       });
   const rootReducer = (state, action) => {

      if (action.type === "RESET_FORM") {
        const { r1 } = state;
        console.log(r1);
        state = { r1};

        }

      return appReducers(state, action);
    };
```

Comment: https://alligator.io/redux/reset-state-redux/ Used this as reference but mine does not work as expected as the whole app reloads

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your reducers, now when you get the `RESET_FORM` action, just the 
`formSubmissionReducer` will react to that, the `reducer1` will just return the state.
Take a read on [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers), they explain that better than me.

```js
const reducer1 = (state, action) => {

      ... // swtich statment
      return state;
    };
    
    const formSubmissionReducer = (state, action) => {

      if (action.type === "RESET_FORM") {
        // it will update the form variable inside the `formSubmissionReducer` state
        return state = {...state, form: action.payload};
      }

      return state;
    };
    
    
   const rootReducer = combineReducers({
       r1: reducer1, 
       formSubmissionReducer: formSubmissionReducer
   });
```

Comment: I have already separated the reducers.Have 2 files namely reducer1.js and formSubmisiionReducer.js.Its in index.js that I combine them.

Comment: Create a codepen to show your problem and will be easy to help you